# Quickly extract value using xpath

Tags: xpath

Getting a little ahead of myself so bear with me if this sounds primitive.

Basically I want to be able to extract a value from a specific xpath within multiple web pages. These will be product pages which will all have a value against this specific xpath.

E.G

```
//*[@id="orb-modules"]/div[1]/section[3]/div/div[1]/a/div[2]/div/h2/span
```

I am able to find the value by using the Chrome console and $x command (however this returns the whole element as opposed to just the text value).

The goal is to have a quick way to select and copy this value while clicking through multiple web pages, without the need of performing the same command in the Chrome console each time.

Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) and its `--xpath` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also create a bookmark with this URL, any title:

```
javascript:alert(document.evaluate("//*[@id="orb-modules"]/div[1]/section[3]/div/div[1]/a/div[2]/div/h2/span", document, null, 0, null).iterateNext().textContent)
```

If you try to open this bookmark while on relevant page, you will be alerted :)

Comment: That's fantastic alamar! And simple! Also I realised you can copy straight from the alert box, even better! Thanks again :)

Comment: Sorry to ask another question, how would I return more than 1 value? Ie there are multiple spans and I want all values?

Comment: @JimmySumpter `javascript:x = document.evaluate("//*[@id="orb-modules"]/div[1]/section[3]/div/div[1]/a/div[2]/div/h2/span", document, null, 0, null); while(n=x.iterateNext()) {alert(n.textContent)}`
If you need it more fancy, time to pick up some programming

Answer (score 0):

Since this is programming community, I will recommend you to employ Java + TagSoup library. There you can read web pages, perform xpath on them, write results (somewhere).

I'm not ready to name any command-line tooling that will handle "wild" HTML.